# Add vertical spacing between epigraphs

Tags: spacing, epigraphs

I am writing a thesis and would like to add some vertical spacing between epigraphs inside a \begin{epigraphs} environment at the start of my chapters.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\setlength{\epigraphrule}{0pt}
\onehalfspacing
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{.95\textwidth}
\begin{epigraphs}
\qitem{``It's a poor sort of memory that only works backwards.'' \\*%
The White Queen to Alice}%
{--\textsc{Lewis Carroll} $\sim$ Through the Looking Glass}
\qitem{\textbf{Science is}, I believe, \textbf{nothing} but \emph{trained and organised common sense}, differing from the latter only as a veteran may differ from a raw recruit: and its methods differ from those of common sense only so far as the guardsman's cut and thrust differs from the manner in which a savage wields his club.}%
{---\textsc{Aldous Huxley}}
\end{epigraphs}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `epigraphs` environment is defined in terms of a `list`; so

```
\begin{epigraphs}\setlength{\itemsep}{<dimen>}
```

will do what you wish.

For setting the `\itemsep` value for all `epigraphs` environments, write

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\epigraphs}{\qitemlabel}{\qitemlabel\itemsep=<dimen>}{}{}
```

after having loaded `epigraph` (we add the setting in the proper place in the definition of `\epigraphs`, which is the command that LaTeX executes when it sees `\begin{epigraphs}`).

Comment: Thanks. That certainly works. Any way of adding it to the start of the document so that it influences all epigraphs (rather than adding it to each epigraph), without influencing other lists?